# Why jquery not set visiblity to div visible css properties?

Tags: jquery

I'm new in `jquery` ,have a this div into my web page:

```
<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" id="Message" style="visibility: hidden;" >
        <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
        <strong>Success!</strong> Indicates a successful or positive action.
    </div>
```

write this jquery code:

```
$(".Message").css("visibility", "visible");
```

but that code can't set visible property to visibility ,what happen?how can i solve that problem?thanks.

Comment: you need to use `$("#Message") ` instead `$(".Message")` @behzad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to be: 
`$("#Message").css("visibility", "visible");`

As you are selecting an element by its ID
For `$('.Message')`, the class name has to be 'Message'